# What is this sort of headgear called?

Tags: costume

It's a type of headgear that covers the forehead, the back of the head and sides of the face, but does not cover the top of the head or the face. Having said that, it comes with a few variations.

[image: Gambit looking ready to fight.]

A. Gambit. A character created by Chris Claremont and Jim Lee. Appeared in “The Uncanny X-Men” in 1990. His headgear not only covers his chin and neck, but also seems to extend to the rest of the costume.

[image: Matrix in the middle of a fight.]

B. Matrix. A character that appeared in the video game “Time Killers”, which was released in November 1992. Her headgear does not cover her chin or neck.

[image: Miss Haliday facing a threat that she never saw coming.]

C. Miss Haliday. A character created by Max Autohead and Matthew Hatton. Appeared in “Cyberswine” in January 1995. Her headgear covers her chin and neck, but does not extend to the rest of her outfit.

[image: Meanstreak looking very cocky.]

D. Meanstreak. A character created by Ron Lim and John Francis Moore. Appeared in “X-Men 2099” in 1993. His headgear does not cover his chin, but it seems to extend to the rest of the costume.

What these examples have in common is that they all appeared in the 1990s. I have heard it said that fans generally consider this headgear dated at best and laughable at best. After all, why would you wear headgear if it doesn’t even protect your face or the top of your head?

I just wish I knew what this type of headgear is called.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why a superhero should wear such a headgear. It does not conceal his identity nor protect the head. Do they wear it just for show?

Comment: I think the name for that is coif? Knights used to wear it under the helmet. But mail coif usually had hair covering so... Some sites call it hero balaclava but I don't think it has a name.

Comment: I think the inspiration comes from skiing suits. Or maybe ice skating/ ice running suits. Gambit is Canadian.  This is how 80s skiing equipment looked like https://i.pinimg.com/736x/54/d3/e6/54d3e696155478a6b8f607306d7ba705--ski-vintage-vintage-style.jpg

Comment: Another picture: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/fa/e4/65/fae4650751f1468a4b97a55c12b66870.jpg

Comment: @jo1storm: If I'm not mistaken, those skiers just wear regular headbands, nothing that somehow frames the the face in a non-trivial way like in the OP's sample images.

Comment: @jo1storm Gambit is specifically Cajun rather than Canadian, so probably not inspired by winter sports.

Comment: *Robocop*, 1987

Comment: It’s a good question but it might also fit the question style over on the English Language and Usage stack (even though I don’t think I’ve seen this fashion outside of comics).

Comment: Flash Gordon wore that sort of headgear. Maybe that is where it originated? https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexternal-preview.redd.it%2FuGG_Yx3oHBl9EjkeP_gkK93Yk6S4Z1iDHgSOKs8RoH4.jpg%3Fauto%3Dwebp%26s%3Dd379d3b65cb801052976d8d4644db322dfa38710

Comment: The Silver Age Kid Flash is also an earlier example.

Comment: Jack Kirby liked drawing non-masking facial wear, and this was one of his go-to designs.

Comment: *comic-coif* - the silly kind that showcases the hair. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_coif "the mail coif was never placed directly on the skull, but onto a thick shock-absorbing padding made from leather, textile, hair, etc. Increased thermal insulation led to faster overheating of the wearer, which was of major concern for armoured combat." - A *coif stocking* with a top vent for fan service so that we know if they're blonde or redhead.